# what is _UIBaselineLayoutStrut

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the error `AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for _UIBaselineLayoutStrut` when using autolayout on my ios project (written in swift).  I can't figure out what ui element this is coming from.  Anyone have any advice for how i can track this down or what this could possibly be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [runtime headers](http://developer.limneos.net/?ios=11.1.2&framework=UIKit.framework&header=_UIBaselineLayoutStrut.h), it is a private UIKit class derived from (also private) `UITextFieldLabel`.

You probably have a `UITextField` and some constraints involving its baseline. In that case you can spot the `_UIBaselineLayoutStrut` by listing the constraints affecting the text field's vertical layout (check for more [debugging tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html) in Auto Layout Guide):

```
(lldb) po myTextField.constraintsAffectingLayout(for: .vertical)
```

Sample output (see #0 and #3):

```
▿ 6 elements
  - 0 : <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6000000b3aa0 _UIBaselineLayoutStrut:0x7fb249616990.height == 21 Hug:1000 CompressionResistance:1000   (active)>
  - 1 : <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6000000b3da0 UITextField:0x7fb24b00c000.height == 30 Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750   (active)>
  - 2 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009ad60 UITextField:0x7fb24b00c000.lastBaseline == UIView:0x7fb249616170.centerY   (active)>
  - 3 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000915d0 V:|-(4)-[_UIBaselineLayoutStrut:0x7fb249616990]   (active, names: '|':UITextField:0x7fb24b00c000 )>
  - 4 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008b680 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fb249616170.height == 568   (active)>
  - 5 : <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000091080 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x7fb249616170.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fb24960ef60 )>
```

Think of it (roughly) as an auxiliary view to which the constraints are actually applied when you constrain to a text field's baseline.

`AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for _UIBaselineLayoutStrut`, in turn, means Auto Layout doesn't have enough information to work out an exact position for your `UITextField` based on the constraints you provided. [Ambiguous Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AmbiguousLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH18-SW1) should be a good starting point for investigation, together with the debugging tips mentioned above.